# How to prevent Silverlight Caching external XML files

Tags: silverlight, caching

I have a Silverlight5 application (XAP) and it is heavily reliant on XML request to the server.

The app will request a file http:..../Menu.xml which is constantly updated by the server.

When I view the XML file in the browser it is fine, however the Silverlight acts as if it is using an older cached version of this file.

I have added a random string parameter to the XML uri by appending  "?=random" to the end of the XML URL but I still get the same issue.

```
   file_uri_path = "http://adomain.com/.../Menu.xml";

   XmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(GetCCFKPath(file_uri_path));



   public static string GetCCFKPath(string path)
   {
       Random r = new Random(256780);

       int random = r.Next(20000);

       return path + "?ccfk=" + random ;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably only a problem with IE ... do you have the same problems with Chrome?

See this [thread here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/silverlight/en-US/052f9dbf-0783-44da-be95-32335cc4a5f3/ie-problems-with-dynamic-xml), for a possible resolution. It uses the following script to get the xml.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.send(null);
if(!request.getResponseHeader("Date")) 
{
  var cached = request;
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var ifModifiedSince = cached.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
  ifModifiedSince = (ifModifiedSince) ?
    ifModifiedSince : new Date(0); // January 1, 1970
  request.open("GET", url, false);
  request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", ifModifiedSince);
  request.send("");
  if(request.status == 304) 
  {
    request = cached;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a credible approach to try.  You could use `WebClient.GetWebRequest` to add that "If-Modified-Since" header.